# SaveAs Template With External Data Connections

Tags: excel, vba, save-as, excel-external-data

I have been hunting for an answer to this for almost an hour now with no luck. I have an Excel Macro Enabled Template which saves the template as a new name (still as a .xltm) but unfortunately this new file becomes corrupt because my template contains external data connections and I am using `Application.DisplayAlerts = False` to bypass any prompts upon saving. I do not want users to have to deal with a prompt, but when saving a template file with external data connections a prompt appears stating "This workbook contains external data. Do you want Microsoft Excel to clear the data before saving the template, and then automatically refresh the data whenever the template is opened?" with Yes, No and Cancel buttons. What I need is for the No to be selected so the user does not see this prompt and the template is saved without that feature. Is this possible?

Note: If I just leave the `Application.DisplayAlerts` as False, when the new template file is opened an error message is received stating the file is damaged because that external data prompt was never addressed. Not what I want to see at all.

Example of code:

---

```
Application.DisplayAlerts = False

Dim strSaveTool as String

strSaveTool = [TL_Loc] & "\New Template Name.xltm" 'where [TL_Loc] holds the directory path

ThisWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=strSaveTool, FileFormat:=53
```

---

Comment: Check this out @LouFapp. Might be the answer you are looking for: https://superuser.com/questions/697844/how-do-i-find-the-external-data-in-an-excel-workbook-that-appears-to-have-none

Comment: Mech, thank you for the quick response, but that post does not address my question. I need the data connections I have created to pull data in from other sources. What I am looking for is a way to save the file as a template without having to have the user manually deal with the prompt. I need the macro to select No to the prompt and continue on.

Comment: @LouFapp does this solve your issue? [How to control the startup message about updating linked workbooks in Excel](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/troubleshoot/excel/control-startup-message) or alternatively [Control when external references (links) are updated](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/control-when-external-references-links-are-updated-21e995b5-bab1-4328-8ab3-dd357fe0e653) or [How do I save my workbook as a template](https://www.event1software.com/kb-all-products/how-do-i-save-my-workbook-as-a-template/)

Comment: Hi Peh, thank you for the recommended links but none of them address the prompt when saving a template with data connections (in my case to delimited .txt files). They all speak to opening a workbook that contains connections or links. I need to save a template using VBA and have the macro address the option to clear the data before saving the template, and then automatically refresh the data whenever the template is opened. I can't believe Microsoft didn't address this in .SaveAs properties. It's driving me BONKERS!

Comment: @LouFapp Yes, I know they speak about opening. But did you actually try it? I could imagine that it handles both opening and saving once you adjust that setting and the tamplate got saved (as template again). Then reopen it and checkout if it works then. Mirosofts documentation is sometimes weird and some functions are not well documented. So worth a try. • If that doesn't help, I assume it is not possible. • *(side note: If you address peoples name with `@` in the comments they get notified that there is a message)*

Answer (score 0):

@PEH I am using sendKeys "N"  ... Using your code add SendKeys "N" before the line that raises the prompt.  DisplayAlerts needs to be on otherwise the prompt assumes Yes.

To figure out what Key to send experiment on the prompt concerned ..  for the - 'This workbook contains external data etc' prompt  ... Typing N is accepted in place of clicking NO

Application.DisplayAlerts = TRUE   '  False

Dim strSaveTool as String
strSaveTool = [TL_Loc] & "\New Template Name.xltm" 'where [TL_Loc] holds the directory path

SendKeys "N"
ThisWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=strSaveTool, FileFormat:=53